# Cucumber Scenario : giving an empty String as value of parameter in a scenario step

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I have a step implemented like this:

```
@When("I add an attribute named '(.+)' with unit '(.+)' to the item named '(.+)'")
public void addAttributeToAndItem(String attributeName, String unitName, String itemName){
     .....
}
```

in my Cucumber Scenario, i would like to add and attribute not having a unit, so the value of "unit name" should be and empty String. how can I specify this empty String in to my Scenario step.

I tried this one:

```
    Scenario: add attribute to an item
        When  I add an attribute named 'Color' with unit ' ' to the item named ' Car'
```

but it does not work. The ' ' is always seem as a value (a space) and not an empty string. please can somebody help me?

Comment: `' '` is a space. use `''` for an empty string or use something else understood as empty in your test step code

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, what bad happens if a <sp> is the unit for color.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it to `''` but then since `(.+)` will match at least one of anything, using `''` will not match the step.

Try using `(.*)` in your step definition which will match an empty string i.e. `''`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly why you need to know that the unit was a null string.  If you follow the suggestions above and enter a `''` then either `(.+)` or `(.*)` will capture two apostrophes.  You can add the following assert line to confirm:

`assert '' == unit`  should fail

`assert "''" = unit` should pass

There may be a way to get it to work with optional captures, but my regex skills are inadequate and I get undefines steps.